# Is there a shortcut to line up = signs in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I seem to remember something but can't remember how to do it. For example is there any easy way to line up:

```
var a = 1;
var aa  = 2;
```

and make

```
var a  = 1;
var aa = 2;
```

Comment: You can do that with a plugin like [code alignment](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) extension has an "Align Assignments" feature. I've never used this particular feature of PPT (I don't like all that blank space in my code) so I can't vouch for it, but if you've installed Productivity Power Tools, the [docs](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef) say you just need to hit Ctrl+Alt+].